# NUXT3 LazyFetch

Tags: vue.js, fetch, nuxt.js, lazy-evaluation

Example: I have a home page (header, content, footer). In the content, I need to display some data from an API request that is taking too long. (for example 3 seconds).

Now this request blocks the entire page load and renders after 3 seconds when the data from the API is ready. I tried Nuxt3 to use LazyFetch but it doesn't work like I thought it should.

Is it possible to render the header, footer first and then display the content when the API data is ready? (but automatically, no buttons or similar...)
I need the first rendering of the page as fast as possible.

Answer (score 0):

When you don't want the render to be blocked you could use the `onMounted` lifecycle.

This runs after the first render. you can also use a function to load data and assign it to a reactive variable.

```html
<script setup>
const data = ref(null)

const loadData = async () => {
  data.value = await loadSomeData()
}

onMounted(() => {
  loadData()
})
</script>
```

and in your template use

```html
<div v-if="data">
  Data is loaded
</div>
<div v-else>
  Loading...
</div>
```